# Scraping eBay featured collections for product page links

Tags: python, xml, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm attempting to build a web scraping tool using Python and BeautifulSoup that enters an eBay Featured Collection and retrieves the URLs of all the products within the collection (most collections have 17 products, although some have a few more or less). Here's the URL for the collection I attempt to scrape in my code: http://www.ebay.com/cln/ebayhomeeditor/Surface-Study/324079803018

Here's my code so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.ebay.com/cln/ebayhomeeditor/Surface-Study/324079803018'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, 'html.parser')

product_links = []

item_thumb = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'itemThumb'})
for link in item_thumb:
    product_links.append(link.find('a').get('href'))

print product_links
```

This scraper should append 17 links to the list product_links. However, it only works partway. Specifically, it only scrapes the first 12 product links every time, leaving the remaining 5 untouched, even though all 17 links are found within the same HTML tags and attributes. Looking more closely at the page's HTML code, the only difference I found is that the first 12 links and the final 5 are separated by a piece of XML script that I have included here:

```
<script escape-xml="true">
      if (typeof(collectionState) != 'object') {
          var collectionState = {
              itemImageSize: {sWidth: 280, sHeight: 280, lWidth: 580, lHeight: 620},
              page: 1,
              totalPages: 2,
              totalItems: 17,
              pageId: '2057253',
              currentUser: '',
              collectionId: '323101965012',
              serviceHost: 'svcs.ebay.com/buying/collections/v1',
              owner: 'ebaytecheditor',
              csrfToken: '',
              localeId: 'en-US',
              siteId: 'EBAY-US',
              countryId: 'US',
              collectionCosEnabled: 'true',
              collectionCosHostExternal: 'https://api.ebay.com/social/collection/v1',
              collectionCosEditEnabled: 'true',
              isCollectionReorderEnabled: 'false',
              isOwnerSignedIn: false || false,
              partiallySignedInUser: '@@__@@__@@',
              baseDomain: 'ebay.com',
              currentDomain: 'www.ebay.com',
              isTablet: false,
              isMobile: false,
              showViewCount: true
          };
      }
    </script>
```

What is the function of this script? Is it possible that this script is the reason my scraper neglects to scrape the final 5 links? Is there a way to work around this and scape the final five?

Comment: this is happening because the next 5 links are loaded using JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last few are generated through an *ajax* request to *http://www.ebay.com/cln/_ajax/2/ebayhomeeditor/324079803018*:

[image]

The url is made up using *ebayhomeeditor* and what must be some product id *324079803018* which are both in the original url of the page you visit.

The only param that is essential to get data back is the *itemsPerPage* but you can play around with the rest and see what effect they have.

```
params =  {"itemsPerPage": "10"}
soup= BeautifulSoup(requests.get("http://www.ebay.com/cln/_ajax/2/ebayhomeeditor/324079803018", params=params).content)
print([a["href"] for a in soup.select("div.itemThumb div.itemImg.image.lazy-image a[href]")])
```

Which would give you:

```
['http://www.ebay.com/itm/yamazaki-home-tower-book-end-white-stationary-holder-desktop-organizing-steel/171836462366?hash=item280240551e', 'http://www.ebay.com/itm/tetris-constructible-interlocking-desk-lamp-neon-light-nightlight-by-paladone/221571335719?hash=item3396ae4627', 'http://www.ebay.com/itm/iphone-docking-station-dock-native-union-new-in-box/222202878086?hash=item33bc52d886', 'http://www.ebay.com/itm/turnkey-pencil-sharpener-silver-office-home-school-desk-gift-peleg-design/201461359979?hash=item2ee808656b', 'http://www.ebay.com/itm/himori-weekly-times-desk-notepad-desktop-weekly-scheduler-30-weeks-planner/271985620013?hash=item3f539b342d']
```

So putting it together to get all urls:

```
In [23]: params = {"itemsPerPage": "10"}

In [24]: with requests.Session() as s:
   ....:         soup1 = BeautifulSoup(s.get('http://www.ebay.com/cln/ebayhomeeditor/Surface-Study/324079803018').content,
   ....:                               "html.parser")
   ....:         main_urls = [a["href"] for a in soup1.select("div.itemThumb div.itemImg.image.lazy-image a[href]")]
   ....:         soup2 = BeautifulSoup(s.get("http://www.ebay.com/cln/_ajax/2/ebayhomeeditor/324079803018", params=params).content,
   ....:                               "html.parser")
   ....:         print(len(main_urls))
   ....:         main_urls.extend(a["href"] for a in soup2.select("div.itemThumb div.itemImg.image.lazy-image a[href]"))
   ....:         print(main_urls)
   ....:         print(len(main_urls))
   ....:     
12
['http://www.ebay.com/itm/archi-desk-accessories-pen-cup-designed-by-hsunli-huang-for-moma/262435041373?hash=item3d1a58f05d', 'http://www.ebay.com/itm/moorea-seal-violet-light-crane-scissors/201600302323?hash=item2ef0507cf3', 'http://www.ebay.com/itm/kikkerland-photo-holder-with-6-magnetic-wooden-clothespin-mh69-cable-47-long/361394782932?hash=item5424cec2d4', 'http://www.ebay.com/itm/authentic-22-design-studio-merge-concrete-pen-holder-desk-office-pencil/331846509549?hash=item4d4397e3ed', 'http://www.ebay.com/itm/supergal-bookend-by-artori-design-ad103-metal-black/272273290322?hash=item3f64c0b452', 'http://www.ebay.com/itm/elago-p2-stand-for-ipad-tablet-pcchampagne-gold/191527567203?hash=item2c97eebf63', 'http://www.ebay.com/itm/this-is-ground-mouse-pad-pro-ruler-100-authentic-natural-retail-100/201628986934?hash=item2ef2062e36', 'http://www.ebay.com/itm/hot-fuut-foot-rest-hammock-under-desk-office-footrest-mini-stand-hanging-swing/152166878943?hash=item236dda4edf', 'http://www.ebay.com/itm/unido-silver-white-black-led-desk-office-lamp-adjustable-neck-brightness-level/351654910666?hash=item51e0441aca', 'http://www.ebay.com/itm/in-house-black-desk-office-organizer-paper-clips-memo-notes-monkey-business/201645856763?hash=item2ef30797fb', 'http://www.ebay.com/itm/rifle-paper-co-2017-maps-desk-calendar-illustrated-worldwide-cities/262547131670?hash=item3d21074d16', 'http://www.ebay.com/itm/muji-erasable-pen-black/262272348079?hash=item3d10a66faf', 'http://www.ebay.com/itm/rifle-paper-co-2017-maps-desk-calendar-illustrated-worldwide-cities/262547131670?hash=item3d21074d16', 'http://www.ebay.com/itm/muji-erasable-pen-black/262272348079?hash=item3d10a66faf', 'http://www.ebay.com/itm/yamazaki-home-tower-book-end-white-stationary-holder-desktop-organizing-steel/171836462366?hash=item280240551e', 'http://www.ebay.com/itm/tetris-constructible-interlocking-desk-lamp-neon-light-nightlight-by-paladone/221571335719?hash=item3396ae4627', 'http://www.ebay.com/itm/iphone-docking-station-dock-native-union-new-in-box/222202878086?hash=item33bc52d886', 'http://www.ebay.com/itm/turnkey-pencil-sharpener-silver-office-home-school-desk-gift-peleg-design/201461359979?hash=item2ee808656b', 'http://www.ebay.com/itm/himori-weekly-times-desk-notepad-desktop-weekly-scheduler-30-weeks-planner/271985620013?hash=item3f539b342d']
19

In [25]:
```

There is a little overlap with what gets returned so just use a set to store the main_urls or call set on the list:

```
In [25]: len(set(main_urls))
Out[25]: 17
```

Not sure why that happens and have not really tried to figure it out, if it bothers you then you could parse "totalItems: 17" from the ajax call returned source and subtract the length of `main_urls` after the first call and set `{"itemsPerPage": str(len(main_urls) - int(parsedtotal))}` but I would not worry too much about it.

Comment: Is there any EBay API to do this?